# Amazon Auto Scaling and IP access control

Tags: amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services, autoscaling

We hava a project where we have to access a SOAP WS that is access-restricted via IP firewalling.  So each one of our machines need to be added to the firewalling rules by our clients' security team.  Our clients platform runs in hosted in its own DC.

We are also trying to setup an autoscaling group in AWS EC2, in which every newly minted machine will have its own public IP.

What's the best strategy to meet these two requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You put the ASG nodes behind a load balancer, whose IP is persistent through scale up/down cycles.

Comment: That should work, but our balancing tool is ELB, and it's not clear to me if I can use it to route outgoing traffic.